# Get Google Doc ID form list on spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api, google-slides-api

I have a google doc ID (just the ID as a value) in a cell on a spreadsheet. I want to point a Var to grab that value form the spreadsheet (doc ID) and then use it in the `SlidesApp.openbyId`.

For example:

```
var slideId = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get('1aXXXXXXXXXXw', 'Run!E4:E4');
var slide = SlidesApp.openById(slideId);
```

When the script runs and gets to the `var slide = SlidesApp.openById(slideId);` 
I get: *Not found (line 101, file "Code")*

Comment: Although I cannot understand the requirement for using Sheets API in your case, if you can use Spreadsheet service, how about modifying `var slideId = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get('1aXXXXXXXXXXw', 'Run!E4:E4');` to `var slideId = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1aXXXXXXXXXXw').getRange('Run!E4:E4').getValue();`? If you are required to use Sheets API, how about modifying `var slideId = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get('1aXXXXXXXXXXw', 'Run!E4:E4');` to `var slideId = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get('1aXXXXXXXXXXw', 'Run!E4:E4').values[0][0];`?

Comment: Work perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you first get the *range > value*, assign it to a variable & then use that variable in `SlidesApp.openbyId`.

Here's what I'd do -

```
var slideId = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange("A1").getValue();
var slide = SlidesApp.openById(slideId);
```

Please replace the **A1** to wherever the doc ID has been stored.

In case you have a list of doc IDs (unclear per OP), then the solution would slightly vary to **getDataRange** and **getValues** (plural), which would then be routed through a "for" loop so we could iterate through every single doc ID.

Comment: @Ahaze - were you able to achieve what was required?